# Не работает парсинг сайта на selenium

Tags: парсер, selenium

```
import json

import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import  By
#driver = uc.Chrome(version_main=116)
#driver.get("https://maxitter.com/imgur/")

class ImgurParse:
    def init(self, url:str, count:100, version_main = None ):
        self.url = url
        self. count = count
        self.version_main = version_main
        self.data = []

    def __set_up(self):
        self.driver = uc.Chrome(version_main=self.version_main)

    def __get_url(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)

    def __paginator(self):
        while self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[id="next"]' ) and self.count > 0:
            self.__parse_page()
            self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[id="next"]').click()
            self.count -= 1

    def __parse_page(self):
        imgurl = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[id="imgurl"]').text
        #imgimg = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[id="randomimg"]')
        img = self.driver.find_element('//div[@id="randomimg"]/img')
        #src = img.get_attribute('src')
        #img = open("C:/Users/DEXP/Desktop/savi", "w")
        data = {
            'ссылка': imgurl
        }
        self.data.append(data)
        print(imgurl)
        self.__save_data()

    def __save_data(self):
        with open("items.json", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(self.data, f , ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)


    def parse(self):
        self.__set_up()
        self.__get_url()
        self.__paginator()
if __name__ == "main":
    ImgurParse(url='https://maxitter.com/imgur/',
               count=10,
               version_main=117).parse()
```

На старом компьютере где была версия пайчарма 2022.2.1 всё работало, но когда перешёл на новый ноутбук всё сломалось
Ошибок нет но когда запускаю код он сразу завершается

```
ImgurParse(url='https://maxitter.com/imgur/',
               count=10,
               version_main=117).parse()
```

Это место подсвечивается ошибкой Unexpected argument, я думаю из-за этого и не работает но не могу понять почему

Comment: предположу что то с типом параметра version_main не так, может дефолтное значение в конструкторе нужно не None указать а число

Comment: Спасибо , но это не сработало , ошибка вылазит у всех трёх аргументов